# basic sql group by with percentage

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an issue and *NO* it is not homework, it's just a programmer who has been away from SQL for a long time having to solve a problem.

I have the following table:

```
create table students(
    studentid int identity(1,1), 
    [name] varchar(200), 
    [group] varchar(10), 
    grade numeric(9,2) 
)
go
```

The group is something arbitrary, assume it's the following "Group A", "Group B"... and so on.

The grade is on a scale of 0 - 100.

If there are 5 students in each group with grades randomly assigned, what is the best approach to getting the top 3 students (the top 80%) based on their grade?

To be more concrete if I had the following:

```
Ronald, Group A, 84.5
George H, Group A, 82.3
Bill, Group A, 92.0
George W, Group A, 45.5
Barack, Group A, 85.0
```

I'd get back **Ronald, Bill, and Barack**. I'd also need to do this over other groups.

Comment: I think Barack should get an Incomplete at this point :)

Comment: what does 80% mean? best 80% students? 80% percentile (top 20% students)? students that have a score of more then 80 points? students who have a score higher then 80% of the average score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`TOP (n) PERCENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) clause:

```
SELECT TOP (60) PERCENT * FROM students ORDER BY grade DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at first part of [More with SQL Server 2005 : Top n Per Group, Paging, and Common Table Expressions](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/jeffs/archive/2007/03/30/More-SQL-Server-2005-Solutions.aspx). To get top 3 students in each group you can use:

```
SELECT  d.studentid,
        d.name,
        d.group,
        d.grade

FROM   (SELECT  s.studentid,
                s.name, 
                s.group, 
                s.grade
                ROW_NUMBER = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY s.group
                    ORDER BY s.grade DESC)
        FROM    students s
        ) d

WHERE   d.ROW_NUMBER <= 3
```